# ggplot2 scale legend so it fits on page

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

Hi I'm looking for a way to scale a `ggplot2`'s legend (independently of the plot and label sizes), and ideally an automated way to do this scaling so that it fits on the page.

It is very easy to scale the whole plot, including the legend, just by changing the output size but sometimes (especially if I am pasting the plots into a report at a fairly small size) I might need the axis sizes to be fairly large.

I can't find any way to scale the legend as a whole. The options seem to be to manually split it over several rows or to change each element of the legend independently (as I have attempted below); but some of these can be set using `rel` and some can't its hard to know what you'll end up with and it still looks a bit funny.

It seems strange to me that the default behaviour for `ggplot2` is to allow legends to go off the page.

Basically I want the plot like this (which was made in paint using a combination of test.png and test2.png from my example below): [image]

Ideally I'd like it if during the save process it figures out the plot widow and then applies some scaling automatically. Otherwise if I could scale down with a percentage that what be second best option.

Reprex of a simple example. **WARNING it saves to a c:\temp folder**

```r
library(ggplot2)
testplot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour = Species))+
  geom_point()+geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6, colour = "example line"))+theme(legend.position = "bottom")
ggsave(testplot,filename = "C:/temp/test.png", width = 3, height = 3)
ggsave(testplot,filename = "C:/temp/test2.png", width = 6, height = 6)



test2 <- testplot + theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5,"lines"), legend.text = element_text(size = rel(0.5)),
                 legend.title = element_text(size = rel(0.5)))+
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.6)))

ggsave(test2,filename = "C:/temp/test3.png", width = 3, height = 3)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>